# Posing Overlay Model Over Model Causes Clipping

Tags: animation

Sorry if I'm bad at explaining this, I always stayed away from looking for help online and just try to fix my problems myself, also i'm by no means an animator or even much of a modeler, I'm actually a programmer so excuse me not describing this well and feel free to ask for any needed info to help.

basically i got a cube (the head) inside of another cube (the overlay), they are rigged and have the same weights on but the head deforms more than the overlay, thus creating clipping, i have overlays on each body part but for some reason it's only the head that is giving problems[image: As you can see the two cubes are intersected and creating clipping, or even just an offset between the head and overlay]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two cubes deform in different ways, they surely have different weights. Remember that every deformation is leaded by more than a bone, if a vertex is weighted to one bone only, it moves exactly with that bone, regardeless the value of its weight.

Probably you have the same weights relatively to the head bone, but different weights relatively to some others bones (maybe shoulders and/or arms). To check this, select a vertex and search in the "N" properties panel for the "vertex weights" tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much, I didn't think of other bones impacting the head cause on a similar model i've made that didn't happen, thank you so so much, instead just went and weight painted the shoulders to have 0 weight on the head and head overlay so just a slightly easier way then you recommended, but still wouldn't have figured it out without your help, thanks a ton